# What should I choose if I want to communicate between a .NET core and NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, .net-core, signalr

We have an Electron app that comes bundled with a .NET core application.

These two applications need to be able to communicate, right now we use ancient technology by writing to a JSON file that the .NET core application "polls" from regularly.

We want to upgrade this to use sockets instead. The NodeJS developer want to use socket.io and the .NET Core developer wants to use SignalR.

So the questions are probably:

Does SignalR run fine with Node?

Does Socket.io run fine with .NET Core?

Should we just use standard WebSockets on both ends instead?

Comment: hey, you can also use something like pubnub (checkout https://www.pubnub.com). They provide sdks for mostly all languages and platforms.

Answer (score 1):

1. SignalR can be running on Electron as Client.
2. Socket.io is hard to communicate with .net.
3. **(Recommended)** SignalR on both sides(`.net` as Host, `Electron` as client)

   > [Microsoft docs : Running SignalR Javascript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

   or using websocket protocol in both-side.

As you know Socket.io is a library which implements websocket. so SinalR and Socket.io is not fully matched on each other.

> `socketio4net`(socket.io client on .net) is **not maintained** now.

So if you want to communicated by **socket.io**,
You can running `socket.io` on `Electron` as **Host**, and `.net` as **client** with [`WebsocketPackages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets) (not `SignalR`)